# Obter valor de um TJSONString pelo Firemonkey (Delphi)

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey, firedac, datasnap

boa tarde!

Estou com um problema e gostaria de ver se vocês podem me ajudar.

Possuo um servidor DataSnap, o qual está funcionando normalmente. Nele, eu faço inclusão e consulta na base de dados por dispositivos móveis.

Na função onde faço o cadastro, está configurado assim...

```
function TSM.updateClientes(TObjJSON: TJSONObject): TJSONValue;
var
vCliente: TCliente;
begin
  vCliente:=TJson.JsonToObject<TCliente>(TObjJSON.ToJSON);
  try
    tbUsuarios.Open;

    if not (tbUsuarios.Locate('email', vCliente.Email,[])) then
      begin
        tbUsuarios.Append;
        tbUsuarios.FieldByName('nome').AsString:=vCliente.Nome;
        tbUsuarios.FieldByName('email').AsString:=vCliente.Email;
        tbUsuarios.FieldByName('login').AsString:='@'+vCliente.Login;
        tbUsuarios.FieldByName('senha').AsString:=Encode64(vCliente.Senha, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
        tbUsuarios.FieldByName('data_cadastro').AsDateTime:=Now;
        tbUsuarios.Insert;
        Result:=TJSONString.Create('Cadastro realizado com sucesso.');
      end
    else
      begin
        Result:=TJSONString.Create('Email já cadastrado.');
      end;

  finally
    tbUsuarios.Close;
    VCliente.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Eu consigo imprimir essas *TJSONString* num *TMemo*, via *Bind Visually*, mas não consigo pegar o valor dessas mensagens e colocar num **ShowMessage** por exemplo. 
No TMemo, é exibido conforme abaixo (JSONValue)...

```
{
 "result":
 [
  "Cadastro realizado com sucesso."
 ]
}
```

Alguém sabe me informar como faço pra pegar apenas as mensagens desses Result pelo client?

Desde já, agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo como:

```
    var
      vJson: String;
      vObjeto: TJSONObject;
    begin
      vObjeto := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONValue_AQUI) as TJSONObject;
      vJson := vObjeto.Get(0).JsonValue.ToString;
      vObjeto.Free; 
    end;
```

Ou mais enxugado:

```
ShowMessage(TJSONObject(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONValue_AQUI)).Get(0).JsonValue.ToString);
```